# How to setup multiple point of interest in DJI Mobile SDK

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I'm making an app that create automatic missions for DJI drones. How should I approach seeing up multiple points of interest?

Currently in my applications, I send an array of waypoints following MAVLink protocol (I do not use mavlink, it only a way to make everything follow a standard). Then I convert this array into waypoints used in DJI Mobile SDK. When I find a waypoint specified as a Point of Interest(POI or ROI), I save it as a waypoint but I do not add it to the waypoint list, every waypoint after this one, I make its heading and gimbal point towards the current POI. There are also a recursion that checks if is necessary to add a new waypoint in the middle of the path to adjust heading and gimbal pitch.

This works fine unless drone path goes above the POI, when it happens, the programam generates a bunch of waypoints to adjust gimbal pitch.

Since there is a limit of 99 waypoints per mission, I reach this limit very fast.

Maybe there is another way to tackle this issue. The setPointOfInterest() in dji sdk only allows one waypoint per mission.
Should I create one mission per POI, then use timeline to make them all run together, tried this before but drone freezes in place for a while when switching missions.
Litchi app seems to implemente multiple POIs very well in their app, anyone know how they do it?

Comment: could you figure this out ? I am stuck with the same

Comment: Hi @vishal dharankar, sadly the SDK allows only one POI per mission. You can use Timeline API to set as many missions you need with one POI each, or make manually as I said in my question. Those are the way I found to create a decent multiple POI "mission"

Comment: How quickly it switches the mission in timeline ? I wonder if lichi app does the same

Comment: In my tests, it takes a few seconds to update the new mission. About 3 up tp 10 seconds depending the size of the next mission. For my application, this delay is too big, but maybe for you it is acceptable.